# Different layouts depending on sub resources

Tags: ember.js

Sorry if this is a really obvious questions but I have the following routes:

```
Web.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('orders', function(){
    this.resource("order", {path:":order_id"});
  });
});
```

And for my orders template I have something like:

```
<div class="someclass">
{{outlet}}
</div>
```

And what I want todo is:

```
{{#if onOrderRoute}}
  <div class="someclass">
{{outlet}}
{{else}}
  <div class="someotherclass">
{{/if}}
</div>
```

I was wondering what the best way of doing this is, or am I mising something?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. The view has a [layoutName](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_layouts) property you can use to specify your layout. Another option is to specify a property on your child view, and then your template can bind to that by using the view property.

For example:

```
Web.OrderView = Ember.View.extend({
    childView: true
);
```

Then, in your template you bind to `view.childView`

```
{{#if view.childView}}
<!-- code goes here -->
{{/if}}
```

Further, you can even create a mixin and then just inject that mixin into every view.

```
Web.ChildViewMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    childView: true
});

Web.ChildView = Ember.View.extend(ChildViewMixin, {
});
```